# Funnel Legacy SQL Filter problems - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

we're trying to use script for a funnel for google BigQuery that Doug Mackenzie created linked here:http://online-behavior.com/analytics/funnel-analysis
We have run into some problems with our SQL call.

We're trying to use a filter from a hits.customDimensions.index = 20 where the value is 1. These values are always present so a simple filter such as the ones used as examples in his introduction is unfortunately not adequate. 
A filter such as:
    `WHERE hits.customDimensions.index = '20'` Does not filter what we need to have filtered.
Rather we need (we imagine) something like this:

`WHERE MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=20,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) WITHIN hits as locked= '1'`

This is how we've tried doing it:

```
FROM (
    SELECT
      fullVisitorId,
      visitId,
      MIN(hits.hitNumber) AS firstHit,
      MAX(IF(hits.isExit, 1, 0)) AS exit
    FROM(
      SELECT
      *,
      MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=20,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) WITHIN hits as locked,
      FROM
      TABLE_DATE_RANGE([[dataset.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-06-01'), TIMESTAMP('2017-06-04'))
      )
    WHERE
      REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath, '^/plus/.*/[0-9]')
      AND totals.visits = 1
      AND locked= '1'
    GROUP BY
      fullVisitorId,
      visitId) s0
```

This returns the error:
Error: Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields customDimensions.index and hits.kunde. ; Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields customDimensions.value and hits.kunde.

We have seen that there are some suggestions to use `FLATTEN` on problems with the above mentioned error. However this did seem to give syntax errors:

```
  FROM (
    SELECT
      fullVisitorId,
      visitId,
      MIN(hits.hitNumber) AS firstHit,
      MAX(IF(hits.isExit, 1, 0)) AS exit,
      MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index=20,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) WITHIN hits AS locked
    FROM
      FLATTEN(TABLE_DATE_RANGE([[dataset.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-06-01'), TIMESTAMP('2017-06-04')),hits.customDimension)
    WHERE
      REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath, '^/plus/.*/[0-9]')
      AND totals.visits = 1
      AND locked = '1'
    GROUP BY
      fullVisitorId,
      visitId) s0
```

Just gives the error: `Error: Not found: Table eb-bigquery:3917183.ga_sessions_`
So any suggestions to how we can get the filter to work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a reason for not using the [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) Version of BQ?

Comment: The script that we're using generates the SQL call does it in Legacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery has evolved a lot since this blog was written and now we have more advanced techniques to process data.

That's the main reason why I asked if you could use the Standard Version of BigQuery as solving this would be easier there. For instance:

```
SELECT 
  fullvisitorid,
  visitid,
  (select min(hitNumber) from unnest(hits) where regexp_contains(page.pagePath, r'^/plus/.*/[0-9]')) firstHit,
  (select max(isExit) from UNNEST(hits) where regexp_contains(page.pagePath, r'^/plus/.*/[0-9]')) exitFlag
FROM `table`
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND EXISTS(select 1 from unnest(hits) where regexp_contains(page.pagePath, r'^/plus/.*/[0-9]'))
AND EXISTS(select 1 from unnest(hits) hits where (select count(value) from unnest(hits.customDimensions) custd where index=20) > 0)
AND totals.visits = 1
```

This query does the same thing and runs faster than the Legacy ones as it avoids first unnesting all repeated fields and then processing the data.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work for my example posted here.

Comment: Folllow up question as this is supposed to be for a funnel for google-bigquery. There is multiple page paths we want to look at, we then want the values from these to be added and then counted. Here we've tried using `full outer join each` for each of these page paths. However here we receive two errors : `Error: UNNEST expression references column hits which is neither grouped nor aggregated at[x:y]` and that `SELECT` should be within brackets. Any suggestions -  I can post as a new question altogether.

Comment: @Sofu5 just now I saw your comment. Looks like you already did ask this question though :)